# Jekyll refused to build, even though it build before

Tags: html, github, web, jekyll, github-pages

I have a project that refused to build on Github pages. Very wierd thing is I only added a google anaytics tag on it but it can't build.

Here is the commit that GitHub does not builds
https://github.com/ojiii/tale/commit/466b1133df9fc6a24d80ddafea686cc480b630ef

and here is the commit that GitHub builds
https://github.com/ojiii/tale/commit/4733ac841f24b0f0e915fa171556cf2a7bfae3b7

The only difference between the two is that I added Google Analytics tag on my header.
The weirder thing is that when try to build it on my computer with the previous 2 commit and this commit https://github.com/ojiii/tale/commit/45e718fa3084e2552c409d8b0f1f1c047a253b13 it fails to build. The error message for all the failures are 
`` There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: There are no gemspecs at C:/Users/pikachu/Documents/Workspace/tale. Bundler cannot continue. `` GitHub builds it before (except for latest commit) and even published it.

Comment: @marcanuy is right, use github-pages to test your site locally with the github pages setup. But I've forked your repo and everything is ok (analytics is present). Simply try to commit again, I'm afraid it was a github hiccup.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I saw your fork earlier was surprised someone forked my repository, turns out it was from stackoverflow! Thank you for the help. I tried marcanuy's answer last night but the build spits out 2 warnings but I think that's my installation.

Comment: You are right! It builds!

Comment: I was using a theme, and this line in `Gemfile` was breaking the build for me `gemspec` (I hadn't copied across the .gemspec file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug locally replace your Gemfile with this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'github-pages'
```

Now you will be using the same gems Github uses.

The above error should be preventing your site to build, so fixing that should bring your site alive again.